# jQuery - How to keep vertical position of an element relative to screen?

Tags: jquery, css

I think I'm nearly there but what I want to accomplish is a little bit unique.

I have a number of panels divided in 2 columns and each panel can trigger a toggle of expand/compress.

The thing is I want to keep vertical positioning of an element that the toggle was triggered from so users don't lose the track of the panel they wanted to see in expanded mode.

I can't get the scroll position of bottom panels to move up when expand is triggered.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    var target = $('#' + id);
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);

    $('.fa-compress').toggle();
    $('.fa-expand').toggle();
    $('.row > div').toggleClass('col-xs-6').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
});
```

This is my 
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/oumaqgft/11/)

**UPDATE

By default, users will start from compressed view (2 column)
and if they wish to view one of the panel, will click on expand button - when this is clicked, expand animation will happen and I want this expand animation happening without moving the triggered panel. That's what I meant by keeping vertical positioning.

Comment: Do you want to expand all panels or just the one that was clicked?

Comment: I need to expand all panels, the way panels expand is working fine but even though expand happens for all panels, the triggered panel should be in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm honestly not completely sure what you're asking for. but here goes.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    //your stuff     here first

    var container = $(this).closest('panel');

    //gets elements distance to the top of the viewable screen
    var viewableOffset = $(container).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(); 

   //makes the panel fixed and glued at the distance to the top of screen
   // the same as when you clicked it. keeping its vertical position         
   $(container).css('position', 'fixed');
   $(container).css('top', viewableOffset + 'px');

}
```

edit: sorry, didnt include how to keep the left-position, but you have enough to figure it out :)

---

### Edit 1

Now I understand. If you need the panel to stay at the same place on the screen as it goes into full-width, without scrolling the page: You need to move (append) the element in the dom.

The psudo to this is calculating the amount of predecessors, then appending the selected panel after half that amount, rounded down to the closest even number.

Lets say you expand panel  5.

Amount of siblings before #5 is  4

4 / 2 = 2

putting 5 after #2 in expanded view vill put #5 at the height it was in the small view.

Somehow saving the original position of #5, and reverting it to that position when minimizing will put everything back to original.

Comment: Thanks but they can't be fixed position because once they are done with the triggered panel, they will need to scroll through to other panels. Please see my update.

Comment: I explained the math in an edit. How every you want to  solve it depends on your flavor, i guess

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var $target = $(this).closest('.panel');
    var targetIndex = $('.panel').index($target);

    var singleHeight = $target.outerHeight(true);
    var totalHeight = singleHeight * targetIndex;

    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: totalHeight
    }, 500);    

    $('.fa-compress').toggle();
    $('.fa-expand').toggle();
    $('.row > div').toggleClass('col-xs-6').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/puye3ode/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your input but scroll doesn't seem to move to #4 and #5 when expand is triggered from those panels?

Comment: Sorry I don't see the difference in JSFiddle? I want to achieve the scroll to follow panels that triggered expand in expand view.

Comment: So what is not working for you? E.g. you click the expand button on panel 2 and the window scrolls to show panel 2.

Comment: It doesn't scroll as far as I can see. If you look at my demo, there is actual scroll movement to panel 2 to keep it in focus.

Comment: Yes. I think there was a misunderstanding here. By keeping vertical position, I don't mean to keep them always at top. Scroll needs to follow the  triggered panel. E.g. if you click expand from panel 4, I need to see panel 4 at the top or center of the screen when expanded.

Comment: What if you adjust the duration like so http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/puye3ode/4/ ?